# How do I interpret a web entity with a null score?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, null, google-cloud-vision

When I make a web detection request to the Google Vision API, I get back a bunch of web entities. The last entity in the list has no score -- that is, 'score' isn't 0, it just returns null. I can't find any Google documentation explaining what a null score means.

I've only seen this happen consistently for one image (so far).

Example of a normal WebEntity which has description, entityId, and score:

```
{
  "description": "Car",
  "entityId": "/m/11afgkh",
  "score": "0.24221982"
}
```

Actual WebEntity that I get:

```
{
  "description": "Unbreakable",
  "entityId": "/g/11f_s_bdwj",
}
```

How should a null score be interpreted? Also... I know this is off topic, but what is the entityId even used for? I can't find much documentation on either of these other than the comments in the code:

```
 /**
   * Overall relevancy score for the entity. Not normalized and not comparable across different
   * image queries.
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.Float getScore() {
    return score;
  }
```

```
  /**
   * Opaque entity ID.
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.String getEntityId() {
    return entityId;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vision API uses [Protocol Buffers v3](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3)

> An unset primitive field has a language-defined default value.

In your case, the score is the default value 0 if score is not in the response.

You can get more info about the entity by sending the entityId to [Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/)